# TypeConversionFailure while inserting empty string in decimal type column

Tags: azure, azure-data-factory

I am trying to insert a null value into a column with Decimal data type. Below is the error I get.

```
ErrorCode=TypeConversionFailure,Exception occurred when converting 
value '' for column name 'xyz' from type 'String' (precision:, scale:) 
to type 'Decimal' (precision:18, scale:0). Additional info: The input 
wasn't in a correct format.
```

I tried multiple solutions like this -

```
@if(equals(activity('Lookup1').output.value[int(variables('i'))].eftEnrollmentUniqueIdentifier,'null'),'NULL',activity('Lookup1').output.value[int(variables('i'))]
```

[image])

I also tried comparing it with empty string '' but it did not help.

Here is the output of the lookup activity that I am inserting into other table
[Lookup activity output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2P3WI.png)

Answer (score 0):

- I gave the same expression and tried to pass `''` empty string and `null` values as input to copy activity and got the same.

[image]

In Copy activity, Value in additional column can be of string only. It does not accept null value there. But the target column is of decimal(18,0). That is the reason, we get this conversion error. In order to meet this requirement, you can use dataflow.

Create a dataflow and create a dataflow parameter. Define the dataflow parameter in the pipeline with the same expression you gave. Refer the below image.

[image]

- In dataflow, add a source tansformation. Then add a derived column and give the parameter value to that column.

[image]

By this way, you can copy the null data into sink.